# Why I'm I getting merge conflicts on files I didn't even touch?

Tags: git, merge, commit, conflict

I'm working on a branch > `my-branch`. When I'm ready to merge with develop, I commit my code and switch to the develop branch. I do a `git pull origin develop`, then `pull` develop and switch back to `my-branch` and do a `git merge origin develop`. I'm getting like **50+** merge conflicts mostly on files *I didn't even touch*. When it's trying to merge my branch with develop it seems like it's asking me to manually merge everything instead of automatically merging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a merge conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43809309/what-is-a-merge-conflict)

Comment: Could your editor be changing invisible parts of the files, like new lines or indenting

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't touch files and you are getting conflicts in there it's more than likely that you have your settings such that git is changing the EOL-format of the files.

https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings

`core.autocrlf`, perhaps?